# Using Mocha with IntelliJ

Tags: mocha.js, intellij-13

I am trying to configure Mocha for IntelliJ, and when Googling, I keep finding posts that say "install the mocha plugin".

I don't have a Mocha plugin. I go to `Settings → Plugins → (install JetBrains plugin) / (browse repositories)` but when I type `mocha` it comes up empty.

(Side question: can anyone tell me the difference between the menu options above, please?)

What am I missing?

These are the posts I've run into so far:

- https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/running-mocha-unit-tests.html
- [How can I run mocha tests remotely on IntelliJ IDEA 13 (or WebStorm)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23793989/how-can-i-run-mocha-tests-remotely-on-intellij-idea-13-or-webstorm)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mocha integration is included with another plugin (I'm going to guess the NodeJS plugin).  If you install that plugin, and then go to manually add a Run Configuration, mocha will be an option .  In the Webstorm 7.0.2 blog post, there is an embedded YouTube video which shows you how to configure a Mocha test directory:

http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2013/11/webstorm-7-0-2-is-available/

Comment: I forgot to mention: I'm using IDEA Ultimate 13.1.5.

Comment: THANK YOU! I got incredibly frustrated using IDEA Ultimate 14, reading their documentation which instructed me to download the Mocha plugin (which no longer exists since it's bundled with NodeJS plugin) after installing the NodeJS plugin.

Comment: Is Mocha integration not included in Version 12? I can't see mocha anywhere under the Run Config options.

Comment: Is the NodeJS plugin installed?  If it is, then Mocha integration is not included in that version of the plugin.

Comment: how is an answer that is sending you to read an article that sends you to watch a video with a broken link the accepted answer? Isn't the whole point of StackOverflow to give you the answers in a simple fashion on this page? I could have read articles on my own

Answer (score 2):

You dont have to install Mocha Plugin. Infact Mocha is not available as plugin in IntelliJ IDEA IDE. Just install Node & using node package manager install Mocha.

From Menu click on `Run > Edit Configuartion` Click on Add button (+ icon) & select Mocha from here. Specify `Working Directory, Test Directory, Mocha Package` (Local node module folder where Mocha is installed) & you are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

Mocha comes bundled with the NodeJS plugin in IntelliJ Idea.

If you don't have it, install the NodeJS plugin:

```
Preferences > Plugins > NodeJS
```